# Java 1.7 CachedRowSet.populate() turns MySQL TINYINT(1) into Boolean. Can this be disabled?

Tags: java, mysql

As the title states, feeding a ResultSet that contains a TINYINT(1) column to a CachedRowSet throught its populate() method will convert the values in that column to booleans with values false for 0 and true for anything above. This loses the original value and makes a getInt() call for that column throw an exception.

Can this behaviour be disabled? TINYINT(1) is also very useful for hardcoded types and statuses. It's a number with 1 digit, not a number where 1 is max value. No reason to treat it as boolean, really.

Anything I can do to disable this when instantiating CachedRowSetImpl?

Comment: Did you try running MySQL in [ANSI mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi)?

Answer (score 0):

Use [cast](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) in your SQL, so you're getting back a normal int:

```
select cast(tinyIntColumn as int) from someTable
```

Comment: Not much of an option. I'd rather turn all TINYINTs into INTs as I've already done.